# how to make bullets appear incrementally r presentation

Tags: r, rpres

How does one make an R presentation display bullets incrementally. By "R presentation" I mean Rstudio's .rpres -I know this can be done in ioslides, beamer, slidify, etc. but I cannot find any documentation about how this is implemented in .rpres. Is this possible without css? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through random trial and error:

```
Title
========================================================
author: Name
date: 10/10/10
autosize: true
incremental: true
```

Comment: This also works at the individual *slide* level, by including the same `incremental: true` below the slide header.